# Triangle Type given three points (acute, obtuse, right)

Tags: java, geometry

Goal: Given three (x,y) coordinates, determine whether the triangle is acute, obtuse, right, or cannot form a triangle. My problem starts when I put in condition for Acute Triangle. The way I have it entered, the program would not go further than Acute Triangle. In summary, "It's either a right triangle or else Acute." Please help me fix it. Appreciate the help. Here is my code so far:

```
        //Calculate change in x for distance formula
        delta_x1 = (x2-x1)*(x2-x1);
        delta_x2 = (x3-x2)*(x3-x2);
        delta_x3 = (x3-x1)*(x3-x1);

        //Calculate change in y for distance formula
        delta_y1 = (y2-y1)*(y2-y1);
        delta_y2 = (y3-y2)*(y3-y2);
        delta_y3 = (y3-y1)*(y3-y1);
        //Calculate distance foe each of the three sides if not CO-LINEAR
        side1 = Math.sqrt(delta_x1 + delta_y1);
        side1 = Math.round(side1*side1);
        side2 = Math.sqrt(delta_x2 + delta_y2);
        side2 = Math.round(side2*side2);
        side3 = Math.sqrt(delta_x3 + delta_y3);
        side3 = Math.round(side3*side3); 

        if ((side1 + side2 == side3) || 
            (side1 + side3 == side2) ||
            (side2 + side3 == side1)) {
            System.out.println ("Right Triangle!");
        }
        else if ((side1 + side2 > side3) ||
                 (side1 + side3 > side2) ||
                 (side2 + side3 > side1)) {
            System.out.println("Acute Triangle!");
        }
        else if ((side1 + side2 < side3) ||
                 (side1 + side3 < side2) ||
                 (side2 + side3 < side1)) {
            System.out.println("Obtuse Triangle!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Can't form a triangle.");
        }
```

Comment: It is very confusing that the variables `sideX` actually are the squares of the sides.

Comment: Your conditions are incorrect and obtuse triangles are being eaten up at acute. Consider a triangle with sides 10, 10, and 18, which is obtuse. 10^2 + 18^2 > 10^2 therefore acute is not valid. You should be using the greatest value as the statement to the right side of the lt sign, not trying for all three.

Comment: Why are you calling Math.round()?  All of your variables should be `double` for this problem.

Comment: Thanks guys for the suggestions. It helped a lot. I was using Math.round() to square back the square root (10 != 10.0000001). But it was not needed. @Compass How do I insert greatest value statement aka longest side? I think that would make my check simpler and more efficient code. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @cats2385 the answer below, #4 explains it. I erred in logical explanation and couldn't edit, and by that point, a proper answer had been formed. You want all three a2 + b2 > c2 to be valid, not just one. So, basically, your right angle check is fine, then for your acute check, (a2 + b2 > c2 && a2 + c2 > b2 && b2 + c2 > a2) , else we know for sure it's an obtuse triangle. Your last statement, can't form a triangle, is actually a bit harder to find. 3 of the exact same points (0,0) (0,0) (0,0) would be considered a triangle in this program.

Comment: Ok thanks @Compass ! I have to have "Can't find triangle." I think I know how. I'll set the condition where as long as the slopes of each of three lines are not equal, then it's one of the three triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three serious errors and two misdemeanours.

(1) Don't call the squares of the sides `side1, side2, side3`.  It's very confusing, but it won't make your program give incorrect results.

(2) You take square roots, then square the results.  This is pointless, but again, it's not really an error.

(3) Don't round the squares of the sides as they may not be integers.  This will introduce errors if the side lengths are not integers.

(4) Replace `||` with `&&` in the condition for acuteness.  All three of these inequalities must hold for the triangle to be acute.  This is the error that's making it all go wrong.

(5) For the obtuseness condition to be correct, you'd want the original side lengths, not the squares of the sides; and you'd want `<=` in place of `<`.  But since the three lengths have come from distances between actual points, all that's left to check at this stage is whether the points are collinear.  For this, it would be less prone to rounding errors if you use an equality such as `(x2-x1)*(y3-y2)==(y2-y1)*(x3-x2)` which will be true if and only if the points are collinear.

Comment: Thank you David. It worked! Two questions: 1) Why can I not use the squares of the sides for obtuseness? 2) What happens if I run into co-linear coords? (i.e. (0,0),(1,1),(2,2))? Thanks

Comment: For colinear coordinates, the easiest check would be to take the unsquared elements. So a + b == c || a + c == b || b + c == a. This can be simplified greatly by making c always the biggest value beforehand so you just have to check a + b == c

Comment: In your obtuseness check, you're should really just be checking whether you've got a real triangle or not.  You've already ruled out the cases of it being a right triangle or an acute triangle.  So you've either got an obtuse triangle or collinear points.  That's why you just need to check whether the points are collinear at that stage.

Comment: Thanks @DavidWallace . To clarify, is this what you meant?  Given (x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3), use distance formula to calculate d1, d2, and d3 for the following conditions: 1) d1+d2<d3 2) d2+d3<d1 3) d1+d3<d2.

Comment: Sorry, I guess that needs to be `<=`, not `<`.  If the points are collinear, then one of those three equalities will turn out equal.  But now I'm thinking about rounding errors.  I guess it would be better just to check something like `(x2-x1)*(y3-y2)==(y2-y1)*(x3-x2)`.